# Measures (values) showing only with specific rows selected

Tags: sql, excel, pivot-table, data-warehouse, olap-cube

So I have an OLAP cube with many dimensions and measures defined, some of which are linked from another cube. In Excel, when I try to insert pivot table connected to that cube, in some cases a measures wouldn't show (will retrieve empty values). However, if I additionally choose one specific row (let's say item number) to the table, they would work just fine.

Everything seems to be visible in the views, the warehouse retrieves data correctly through direct query.

Where should I be looking for an error, or how is it possible, that defining row in pivot table would help? [The example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Jrb.png)

Comment: What does your ORD A measure look like?

Comment: CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[ORD A]
 AS ([ORD Type].[ORD Type].&[1], [Measures].[ORD Sum]), 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Orders';  

ORD Type 1 is simply 1, the other option for it is to be 0. ORD Sum is another measure with double DataType. They work just fine for 99,9% of queries, but for some randomly won't (unless I choose row with Item number, then everything is ok).